# Abstract exercise about the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am practicing Calculus problems and the following one caught my attention:

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ a $\cal{C}^1$ function, and let $P\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $F(P)=0$, $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}\ne 0$, $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}\ne 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}\ne 0$.

Justify that you can take locally $x = x(y,z)$, $y = y(x,z)$ and $z = z(x,y)$ around P in such a way that $F(x,y,z)=0$.

Using the notations above, prove that

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -1
$$

The first part is clearly an straightforward application of the Implicit Function Theorem, since each of the non-equalities ensures that the corresponding variable can be write as a function of the remaining two. However, I am not sure about the last part. How could I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the chain rule: since $F(x,y,z(x,y)) = 0$ you have
$$ F_1 + F_3 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = F_1 \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + F_2 \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + F_3 \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 0$$ where $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$ because $y$ and $x$ are independent. Solve for $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ to find
$$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{F_1}{F_3}.$$
Now repeat with the other two partial derivatives and multiply.

Comment: I just realized a moment before you posted, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same question in the future, I worked a little more and realize the second part is just an application of the Chain Rule to $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ and the other two derivatives involved in the equality that we must prove.